# Able to ping my host but getting no route to host

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, ping, telnet, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch service running on `MY_HOST_IP(10.x.x.xx)` and port `9200`. I am able to ping `10.x.x.xx` from my VM, but when I try to connect `elasticsearch` it gives me :

> no route to host exception.

Even when I telnet it gives me same error. I have reloaded my iptables but didn't get expected result.

Even curl command results in the same thing

curl -XGET "http://10.x.x.xx:9200"

```
no route to host
```

Also I am able to ssh from VM to my host machine .

Comment: Is the HOSTequal to the VM? If not, did you enable bridged or host-only networking in the vm guest?

Comment: @gerhardd.its on NAT

Comment: And what does your routing table says? Could you post the output of `ip route show`?

Comment: And is HOST equal to VM, or is VM a guest on HOST? You will need Bridged networking for the HOST in order to be reachable from outside.

Comment: @Igeorget Out put is default via 192.168.122.1/24 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 .
192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.157 metric 100

Comment: @gerhardd. VM is a gues on a host .I have a KVM on centos and the VM guest is running on top of KVM

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an AWS server. netmask, broadcast, subnet, VPC, security and Iam groups all match, I even open my security group to accept connections from anywhere just to test and I still couldn't get this to work